# How do I validate this string in C++?

Tags: c++, string

*A person is asked to enter their credit card number, it has to have 16 digits, after every 4 digits, it has a space or -.*

I have code to check if there are spaces or a hyphen as well as checking if that person entered letters instead.

**The problem with this code is that:** 
       It says out of range when I enter letters and it also says the entry is correct when I entered less than what I set the length to be.
Any ideas where I am going wrong?

```
#include<iomanip>
#include <iostream>
#include<conio.h>
using namespace std;
int main () {
    string creditcardnum;
    bool validcreditcardnum;

    do{
      validcreditcardnum=true;
      cout << "Enter your credit card number\t Enter 4 numbers followed by a space or -\n\t\t";
      cin >> creditcardnum;
      if(validcreditcardnum==false){
         cout<<"Your credit card number is invalid\n\t\t";
      }
      if (creditcardnum.length ()!=19){
         validcreditcardnum==false;
      }
      for(unsigned short a= 0,b=5, c=10, d=15;
                               a<=3,b<=8,c<=13,d<=18;
                               a++, b++, c++,  d++){
         if(!isdigit(creditcardnum.at(a))&&
                !isdigit(creditcardnum.at(b))&&
                !isdigit(creditcardnum.at(c))&&
                !isdigit(creditcardnum.at(d))
               )
             validcreditcardnum==false;
          }
          if(
               creditcardnum.at (4) !=' '||'-'&&
               creditcardnum.at (9) !=' '||'-'&&
               creditcardnum.at (14)!=' '||'-'){
             validcreditcardnum==false;

           }
          while(validcreditcardnum==false);
             if(validcreditcardnum=true)
                cout << "Credit card number is correct";
             return 0;
    }
```

Comment: Yous should also look up the Luhn check for validating credit card numbers: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Luhn_algorithm

Comment: I'd say the best way to do such kind of validation is using [`std::regex`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex), [`boost::regex`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/regex/doc/html/index.html) alternatively, if you can't use [tag:c++11].

Comment: This `if` looks odd: `if(creditcardnum.at (4) !=' '||'-' && creditcardnum.at (9) !=' '||'-'&& creditcardnum.at (14)!=' '||'-')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your original code had a number of other issues.

I modified your code to get it to do what you want. Its not elegant but should work. It works for me.

```
int main()
{
string sCreditcardnum;
char szCreditCardNum[100];
memset(szCreditCardNum, 0, sizeof szCreditCardNum);
bool validcreditcardnum = true;

do {
    if(validcreditcardnum == false) {
        cout << "The credit card number provided is invalid\n\n";
        validcreditcardnum = true;
    }

    cout << "Enter your credit card number\t Enter 4 numbers followed by a space or -\n\t\t";
    cin.getline(szCreditCardNum, 30);
    sCreditcardnum = szCreditCardNum;
    if (sCreditcardnum.length () != 19)
        validcreditcardnum = false;

    for(unsigned short a=0, b=5, c=10, d=15;
        a<=3,b<=8,c<=13,d<=18;
        a++, b++, c++,  d++)
    {
        if(!isdigit(sCreditcardnum.at(a)) ||
            !isdigit(sCreditcardnum.at(b)) ||
            !isdigit(sCreditcardnum.at(c)) ||
            !isdigit(sCreditcardnum.at(d)))
        {
            validcreditcardnum = false;
            break;
        }
    }

    if( (sCreditcardnum.at (4) != ' ' && sCreditcardnum.at (4) != '-') ||
        (sCreditcardnum.at (9) != ' ' && sCreditcardnum.at (9) != '-') ||
        sCreditcardnum.at (14) != ' ' && sCreditcardnum.at (14) != '-')
    {
        validcreditcardnum = false;
    }
}
while(validcreditcardnum == false);
if(validcreditcardnum == true)
    cout << "Credit card number is correct";
return 0;

}
```

Comment: That woks great, few questions, what does memset do and why do programmers use char 100, I thought char was for individual letters only.

Comment: memset is used to initialize memory. An uninitialized block of memory can contain garbage. When working with character buffers it is especially important to have them initialized as there are numerous string functions that rely on the '\0' as a delimiter. As for why I used 100 char buffer, i just picked an arbitrary number larger than 20 to get your program to work. There is nothing special about 100, only needs to be bigger than the size of string you want to read in so that your program doesn't crash.

Comment: char is an 8 bit type that can store individual characters. char [] is an array of char's type which can store strings. Both types are built-in parts of the C/C++ language. In contrast, "std::string" is not built-in C++ type but is a class type that is part of the STL(Standard Template Library) library.

Answer (score 2):

This expression compiles, but it is incorrect:

```
creditcardnum.at (4) !=' '|| '-' && ...
```

The expression above is always `true`, because logical OR operator `||` treats all non-zero values as `true`.

You can rewrite your expression as follows:

```
creditcardnum.at (4) !=' ' && creditcardnum.at (4) !='-' && ...
```

Also, you are using the comma operator where it's not needed:

```
for(unsigned short a= 0,b=5, c=10, d=15;
                           a<=3,b<=8,c<=13,d<=18; // <<== Here
                           a++, b++, c++,  d++)
```

It is enough to write a check on any of the four variables, because they all increment at the same point. Consider rewriting this loop with a single index, and add an "offset" to it as you go (or use a nested loop for the offsets).

Comment: Everything now works, it was missing a getline too for the spaces, Without that extra comma operator you mentioned,it won't compile, One problem remaining, why is the string saying out of range when I enter text

Comment: @user3102359 What text do you enter? (use backward single quotes ``` to delimit the text so that it stays as entered).

Comment: Twoproblems :(, if I enter letters, it says out of range, If I enter 4 letters and all numbers, it says correct entry

Comment: @user3102359 You need `||`s instead of `&&` between `isdigit` calls.

Comment: Why is that, || only for isdigit calls. That solved the out of range string issue. One last question, Any idea as to why it is returning always true, I even set the bool to true outside the bracket

Comment: @user3102359 You may want to post your new code to pastebin.com, because it is difficult to tell what you've got after the edits without seeing it.

Answer (score 0):

Think about how to separate this problem into simpler sub-problems. One obvious one is to check whether a `std::string` object begins with four digits. Another is to check whether an `std::string` object begins with a space or a dash. Write those two functions, and use them to validate the credit card number. If it starts with four digits, remove the four digits; then check whether it starts with a space or a dash, and if it does, remove the first character. Repeat until done.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest treating the credit card number as 4 numbers and not as a character string or set of character strings.

The C++ input functions will read characters, building a number, until a non-numeric character is found.  This means that it will stop when it encounters the space or dash or hyphen between the number groups.

To verify that a group number is 4 digits in length, you check the range:

```
if ((group_number > 999) && (group_number < 10000))
{
  // group number has 4 digits
}
```

Reading a credit card number could be as simple as:

```
int group1;
int group2;
int group3;
int group4;
cin >> group1 >> group2 >> group3 >> group4;
if (group1 < 0) group1 *= -1; // Turn into a positive number
if (group2 < 0) group2 *= -1;
if (group3 < 0) group3 *= -1;
if (group4 < 0) group4 *= -1;
```

Comment: That's a clever approach, Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

At the bottom, your test of the validcreditcardnum flag of validity is incorrect.

```
if(validcreditcardnum=true)
```

It should be if(validcreditcardnum == true). Otherwise you won't get the output messages  "Credit card number is correct".

Comment: Just tried that, it still always return true, if I put in a string with numbers and letters, it says correct. Eg, 1234-wrer-1231-abcd

Comment: I just posted a modified version of your code that works for me. Please check it out.

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this...

If  length not equal to 19 
bool is false

for loop to count up to 19 or less than 20 
    if gets to 4 9 or 14th position add 1 to the count
    if position on count not equal digit then 
    bool equals false
close for loop

for loop counting up to 19 but in groups of five 
    if positon of count not equal to what you require
    bool false 
close for loop